# Windows Disk Manager merging HD Volumes

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

Problem:
Disk 2 of my Desktop, has 3 Volumes: D, E and I. What is happening is that in the middle of volume D, Volume E is appearing and then Volume D continues again. See in the image.

[image]

Objective:
How do I get Disk Manager to show the entire Volume D without Volume E in between? See in the image.

[image]

Comment: Is there a story to this? Did it all of a sudden occur all by itself?

Comment: @Joep van Steen The second part of Volume D, before it was Volume H, but it didn't have any data, so I formatted it and set it to the letter D, but it didn't join with the first part, it stayed in the same place and the Volume E was among them.

Comment: Why would you expect a formatted partition to become part of another partition? You should delete the partition E that you created, then *resize* D to include it.

Comment: @harrymc as the partition is dynamic, I thought that by changing the Volume letter to D, the System would automatically merge the Volume with the same letter into a single Volume... I will then have to make a backup of Volume E before deleting it.